# Bitnami spark docker containers - workes cannot allocate CPUs

Tags: docker, apache-spark, bitnami

I am using the bitnami spark:3.3 images with docker-compose 3.6. I have a 3 node spark cluster (master and 2 workers). The workers use 2 cores and 1G memory. They connect as expected to master. I have a Scala Akka-HTTP server that holds a persistent spark connection but performs no work (for now). But when I run spark-shell, one of the workers produces an error that states "CPUs per task should be > 0". Following this, the spark-shell is unable to allocate an executor (producing Initial job has not accepted any resource). I have tried various combinations of spark conf parameters but with the same result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Michael, could you confirm you're using the correct Spark dependency (3.3) in your Akka server?